# why do I need to set $HADOOP_HOME in hive-env.sh file as it is already set in the .bashrc file

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can any tell me the reason for configuring the $HADOOP_HOME variable in hive-env.sh file as it has already been configured in the .bashrc file during the hadoop configuration.

Comment: if it is already there then may be you need to restart or you can just run `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

If `hive-env.sh` doesn't start with `#!/bin/bash`, or an equivalent shebang, or Hive processes aren't ran with your local user account, then your own bashrc will not be loaded